# In BeanFactoryPostProcessor, how to access variable in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

In spring-boot application, I defined a variable in `application.properties`

```
env=staging
```

Here is a class to access the variable, but its value is `null`

```
@Configuration
public class BeanLifecycleConfiguration {

    @Value("${env}")
    private String env;

    @Bean
    public BeanFactoryPostProcessor changeCustomComponentsToLazyInit() {
        return beanFactory -> {
            System.out.println(env);
            // some logic
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see from the comment, `System.out.println(env);` returns `null`.
Is there a way to get the value of `env`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you add the `@Value("${env}") String env` as an arg to your bean constructor method

```
@Bean
public BeanFactoryPostProcessor changeCustomComponentsToLazyInit(@Value("${env}") String env) {
    return beanFactory -> {
        System.out.println(env);
        // rest of the code
    };
}
```

By doing so, you force Spring to handle the placeholder logic for `$Value("${env}")` annotated value, before the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` bean is created.

In your case the value is `null`, because the bean creation happens before the value insertion.